# how do i know that my iAd will work after app release?

Tags: ios, xcode, iad

How would i know that iAds will be working after my App is released on the store?
on developer release i am getting the banner as seen in the image. Am I on the right track?
[image: current iAd banner]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty much it. Once you've got that on and are seeing test Ads and are following all the proper development rules they will just start showing up in your App a couple of days after it hits the store.